# What is the difference between these two functions?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

$$r(x) = \langle x, x^2-1 \rangle$$

$$f(x)=x^2-1$$

Their graph is the same, but one is called vector valued function while the other one is a regular one. I think I'll never get to understand this subject.

Comment: So you're telling me thirty years from now, when you are 50 or so, you will not understand calculus 3?

Comment: They say that if you didnt get maths when you were 14 or so, your brain is less likely to deal with it at 19. I read and watch explanations and proofs but I tend to forget them

Comment: No problem Tamás this is not difficult at all and you will surly learn it.

Comment: It is very good that you ask things you find difficult, this way you will learn them.

Answer (score 2):

The first function takes $x$ and gives you a vector, the second function takes $x$ and gives you a number.

$$2r(x)=\langle 2x,2x^2-2\rangle$$

$$2f(x)=2x^2-2$$

When people write $|r(x)|$ they mean $\sqrt{x^2+(x^2-1)^2}$.

When people write $|f(x)|$ they mean $|x^2-1|$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an application that makes more evident what are those vectors used for? Because now I'm only seeing that if I draw a line between the points and the origin in the second function i get the same thing except for the arrow :/

Comment: Of course, suppose the position of particle $a$ at time $t$ be given by $r(t)=<t,t^2-1>$, then its speed along $x$ axis will be 1 and it's speed along $y$ axis is $2t$

Comment: Thank you. The magnitude vs. absolute value thing explains a lot. I see that you differentiated the function r(x). What do you mean by speed? Can r'(5)= <1,10> converted to m/s? (I'm sorry that these questions sound so unprofessional)

Comment: To understand that you probably should know more physics,  for now forget about it.

Comment: This function gives the direction of wind in an island at time t $w(t)=<cos(\pi t/A),sin(\pi t/A)>$, $A$ is a constant, suppose the positive side of $y$ axis is the North, can you tell the direction of the wind at $t=A/2$ and $t=5A/4$?

Comment: I am going somewhere, the answers are North and South-West. Good luck!

Comment: w(A/2) = <0,1> and w(5A/4) = <-sqrt(2)/2,-1> if i am not mistaken. I didnt notice your reply. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11728/discussion-between-tamas-and-hhsaffar)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what a graph of a function $g:X\to Y$ is? It is the set of the points
$$\{(x,g(x))\in X\times Y\ |\ x\in X\}.$$

So, the graph of $r$ is made of points of the form $[x,r(x)] = [x, (x,x^2-1)] = [x,x,x^2-1]$. It is a 3-dimensional object, there are $3$ coordinates! Even if the first and the second coordinates are the same.

The graph of $f$ is made of the points $[x,f(x)]=[x,x^2-1]$, so it is a 2-dimensional object.

Having that said, the function $f:X\to X\times X$ which does nothing on the first coordinate (I mean $x\mapsto (x,r(x))$) is not particularly interesting and in some cases we can neglect the first coordinate.